# font.getGlyphID gives KeyError on unicode

Tags: python, svg, unicode, graphics, truetype

I'm trying to render SVG out of an unicode using Python's fonttools:

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.pens.svgPathPen import SVGPathPen

def unicode_to_svg(unicode_char, font_path, output_svg_path):
    # Load the TTF font using fonttools
    font = TTFont(font_path)

    # Get the glyph index for the Unicode character
    glyph_index = font.getGlyphID(unicode_char)

    # Convert the glyph to an SVG path
    glyph_set = font.getGlyphSet()
    glyph_name = font.getGlyphName(glyph_index)
    glyph = glyph_set[glyph_name]
    
    pen = SVGPathPen(glyph_set)
    glyph.draw(pen)
    svg_path_data = pen.getCommands()

    # Create the SVG content
    svg_content = f'''
    <svg width="3000" height="3000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="{svg_path_data}" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    '''
    
    # Save the SVG content to a file
    with open(output_svg_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(svg_content)

# Example usage
font_path = './Nikosh.ttf'
# unicode_char = 'A'
unicode_char = 'ম'
output_svg_path = 'output.svg'
unicode_to_svg(unicode_char, font_path, output_svg_path)
```

But the issue is, it works fine for English alphabets. But when I try to render unicode (such as Bengali) it gives me:

```
KeyError: 'ম'
```

On this line: `glyph_index = font.getGlyphID(unicode_char)`

I simply wanted to take a deeper dive into SVG rendering of different languages, fonts, texts, etc.

How can I resolve this issue? And make it SVG render-able for any unicode character?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use hb-view from the terminal, its a a tiliity included with the harfuzz library, you specify what font to use , and the string you want to render. SVG is supported as an output format. It can render individual characters or strings, correctly rendering text, and allows you to control opentype features used in the rendering. Exporting an svg using fonttools is useful for individual glyphs, but not for rendered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help(font.getGlyphID)
```

> Help on method `getGlyphID` in module `fontTools.ttLib.ttFont`:
>
> `getGlyphID(glyphName)` method of
> `fontTools.ttLib.ttFont.TTFont` instance.
> Returns the `ID` of the glyph with the given name.

The function `char_in_font` comes from my another project, included here *unmodified*… Check its output before passing to `getGlyphID`.

```
from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont
from fontTools.pens.svgPathPen import SVGPathPen

def char_in_font(unicode_char, font):
    '''check if a char is in font, return its glyphName'''
    for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
        if cmap.isUnicode() or cmap.getEncoding() == 'utf_16_be':
            if ord(unicode_char) in cmap.cmap:
                # print(type(cmap))
                auxcn = cmap.cmap[ord(unicode_char)]
                # print(auxcn, type(auxcn))
                return auxcn if auxcn != '' else '<nil>'
    return ''


def unicode_to_svg(unicode_char, font_path, output_svg_path):
    # Load the TTF font using fonttools
    font = TTFont(font_path)

    # Get the glyph index for the Unicode character
    glyph_index = font.getGlyphID(char_in_font(unicode_char, font))

    # Convert the glyph to an SVG path
    glyph_set = font.getGlyphSet()
    glyph_name = font.getGlyphName(glyph_index)
    glyph = glyph_set[glyph_name]
    
    pen = SVGPathPen(glyph_set)
    glyph.draw(pen)
    svg_path_data = pen.getCommands()

    # Create the SVG content
    svg_content = f'''
    <svg width="3000" height="3000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="{svg_path_data}" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    '''
    
    # Save the SVG content to a file
    with open(output_svg_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(svg_content)


# Example usage
font_path = r'D:\Downloads\Fonty\Nikosh\Nikosh.ttf'
# unicode_char = 'A'
unicode_char = 'ম'
output_svg_path = f'output{unicode_char}.svg'
unicode_to_svg(unicode_char, font_path, output_svg_path)
```

**Output:**

```
.\SO\77072040.py
start ""  outputম.svg
```

[image]

```
dir output*.svg
```

> ```
> 09/09/2023  15:55               247 outputA.svg
> 09/09/2023  16:18               751 outputম.svg
> ```

```
start "" outputA.svg
```

[image]

Comment: thanks... really appreciate it...

I just have this question, how can I render any charater?? Right now I'm trying to render `CN` (chinese alphabets) but it's giving me error... any generic methodology??

Comment: Additionally, when multiple glyphs are available for a specific Unicode codepoint, how does the code determine which to use? Or for that matter one-to-many cmap entries as well.

Answer (score 0):

The FontTools approach works well for individual glyphs, if you need to create an SVG image of a single glyph.

If you need to render a string, instead, in a script like Bengali, then FontTools can't do what you need. You need to access a font rendering system, not just the glyphs in the font.

The primary opensource font rendering library is Harfbuzz. To use it, there are the [uharfbuzz](https://github.com/harfbuzz/uharfbuzz) and [vharfbuzz](https://github.com/simoncozens/vharfbuzz) packages.

I'll use `vharfbuzz`:

1. import vharfbuzz
2. Create an instance of the Vharfbuzz class
3. Create a Harfbuzz buffer, shaping the specified text
4. Convert buffer to SVG and write file

```py
from vharfbuzz import Vharfbuzz
vhb = Vharfbuzz('./NotoSerifBengali-vf.ttf')
buf = vhb.shape('বাংলা')
with open('test.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(vhb.buf_to_svg(buf))
```